# How can I splice previous voice recordings to create completely new audio?

Tags: video-games, gameaudio

I'm new to audio work (completely new I've only ever done some sampling for music) but I'm wondering if I can use previous voice recordings to create new words and phrases. I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but I'm having trouble finding answers from searching elsewhere.

Comment: This is a bit broad... if you mean can you turn "I don't like fries" into "I like fries" then, yes, with a simple edit. If you want to turn 10,000 separately spoken words into Siri... then still yes, but you'd need a tad more AI power behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you like to create a new speech signal that sounds natural, there is multiple levels of "sound" that you have to consider:

- base frequency (pitch of your voice)
- overtone frequencies (sound of your voice)
- volume of your voice
- tempo of speech
- transitions of phonemes

The latter point itself comprises very different aspects and is the most difficult to deal with. You can't achieve a natural sounding result just splicing single phonemes if they don't fit to each other in their original recording. This is why many speech synthesis algorithms use [diphone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphone) synthesis.

Adobe's VoCo is like state of the art in manipulating speech signals. It is a neural net / self learning algorithm capable of creating completely new sentences when it has been trained with a large set of sentences of a speaker (about 20 minutes of speech signal is needed). As far as I know, VoCo has not been released to the public for its massive criminal-use potential.